Is it possible to connect batteries series and parallel together and dynamically switches to one another according to the desired outcome at low cost?
Is it feasible to connect batteries in both series and parallel configurations while dynamically switching between them based on specific requirements? A simple and cost-effective procedure could involve using basic relays or low-cost electronic switches. (Adding Buck/boost converter will be expensive and need this on both sides, input and output) Rather than using Buck/boost converter, wiring the batteries to a switchboard, you can easily toggle the connections to optimize voltage or capacity as needed. This approach minimizes complexity and expense while allowing flexibility in battery management. How can this be effectively implemented?
I am interested in exploring the simplest, most efficient, and cost-effective method for dynamically switching battery configurations. If feasible, this approach could potentially replace all battery management systems (BMS) with a more economical technique. Can you provide insights on this implementation?

Of course this is possilble, but I fail to see how this would reduce costs or complexity when you can achieve the same with an adjustable buck/boost converter.

@StarCat I understand that a buck-boost converter allows for variable output voltage, which is advantageous in various applications. However, regarding input, connecting batteries in series is necessary for the converter to achieve higher output voltages. This configuration requires a higher charging voltage to efficiently charge the batteries in a shorter time, or a lower voltage for longer charging durations. This approach can lead to inefficiencies, as managing charging time and voltage levels becomes a critical factor. Am I accurately conveying these concepts?

You should go and read up on how buck/boost converters work @JerinJoze <-- it's an obvious, efficient, reliable and practical solution.

@Andyaka  however, they can be costly for many applications. Are there alternative, low-cost methods for simply switching between series and parallel configurations? I’m seeking straightforward solutions that allow for charging at lower voltages while providing both series and parallel outputs simultaneously, such as using basic relays or manual switching. Any recommendations on these alternatives? simple  and understandable. And how can it efficiently introduced into a system.

@JerinJoze it would help a lot if you can say where the cost of a buck/boost converter would be more than for a system using relays such as for a typical scenario in which you are looking for a specific solution. Without specifics I don't think your "general" question can be properly addressed without this information being provided by you or, someone guessing a scenario that is close to what you want.

Relays are definitely more expensive than a basic buck-boost converter.

@Hearth Can simple three-way switches be configured using parallel and series arrangements in their outputs and charging them in parallel? This approach might facilitate control over lighting circuits in various configurations, potentially enhancing functionality and efficiency with minimal cost?

I think you dramatically overestimate the cost of a switching converter.

@Hearth Could we develop a battery configuration that enables switching between series and parallel modes based on output requirements? In parallel mode, could we effectively reduce the risk of overvoltage during charging and discharging by operating at lower voltages? When high voltage is needed, could the system switch to series mode, despite the challenges of charging? Additionally, with a power delivery system, could we easily access various voltages for different loads? it would be cheep in cost i think

@JerinJoze You are neglecting the fact that batteries are not identical and will wear out to be non-identical. When you switch batteries with relays like you say, you need a system that can handle balancing, so that packs going to be in parallel have equal voltage, or the higher voltage pack will discharge into lower voltage pack with tens or hundreds of amps, melting the relay if it can't handle it. So you cannot make a "simple" system that simply switches batteries with relays, you are facing more complex issues how to manage the batteries to be able to do the simple switching.

Also, I don't think using multiple batteries in parallel reduces the risk of overvoltage by that much.

@Justme so is there any other way to implement my ideas with simple switching system at low cost?
